# Setting constraint deferrable doesn't work on PostgreSQL transaction

Tags: postgresql, transactions, foreign-keys, deferred

This is the situation: I have two tables where the one references the other (say, table2 references table1). When creating these tables, I did set the foreign key constraint as DEFERRABLE and the ON UPDATE and ON DELETE clauses as NO ACTION (which is the default).

But still, when running the transaction below, I get the following error.

Transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;
UPDATE table1 SET blah blah;
UPDATE table2 SET blah blah;
COMMIT;
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  update or delete on table "table1" violates foreign key constraint "table1_column_fkey" on table "table2"
DETAIL:  Key (column1)=(blahblah) is still referenced from table "table2".
```

And table construction:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
    column1 CHAR(10),
    [...]
    PRIMARY KEY (column1)
);

CREATE TABLE table2(
    primkey CHAR(9),
    [...]
    column2 CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(primkey),
    FOREIGN KEY(column2) REFERENCES table1(column1) DEFERRABLE
);
```

What I want to do is to defer the foreign key checking while the transaction is in progress, until it commits. I just can't see why is this error returning and how can I make the transaction work.

Comment: It works like a charm in version 9.0, no problem at all. Should work in older versions as well.

Comment: It's just yesterday I installed PostgreSQL and I use the latest version (9.0.3). I know it should work, as you say. That's why I've almost gone mad trying to find any mistakes causing this error... Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Execute the queries one-by-one, including the SET CONSTRAINTS, and see when things go wrong. Use a as simple as possible datamodel for the test.

Comment: The last time I had this problem, I had the "deferrable" in my reference schema, but I had forgotten to change the actual schema to match the reference schema.  What does "\t table2" show you?

Comment: **@Frank**, [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/sql-set-constraints.html) says "This command only alters the behavior of constraints within the current transaction. Thus, if you execute this command outside of a transaction block (BEGIN/COMMIT pair), it will not appear to have any effect". So, I can't try this.**@Wayne**, I'm not sure what you're saying... Could you explain, please? "\t table2" at psql console shows me "unrecognized boolean value; assuming on. Showing only tuples". Is this ok or did you mean something else? I'm sorry... I'm new to postgresql.

Comment: @frabala, my mistake.  I meant "\d table2".

Comment: Maybe it's usefull to mention that I use only one schema, the "public", which was created automatically and contains all the tables of the database.

Comment: @Wayne Conrad, what this command shows is too much to fit here (limited number of characters), but I guess this is what you're most interested at: `Foreign-key constraints:
    "table2_column2_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (column2) REFERENCES table1(column1) DEFERRABLE`

Comment: @frabala, It is.  And, unfortunately, there goes my idea.  Another great theory destroyed by the available evidence.

Comment: Never mind, Wayne. Thanks for all! Tomorrow is another day... I'll find my way. :)

Comment: Works correctly in 9.0.2 under Windows.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason not to use `ON UPDATE CASCADE` instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was indeed a foreign key constraint violation. I mean, the constraints were indeed deferred within the transaction, but the problem was that at the end of the transaction, after table1 and table2 were updated, the new data were violating a foreign key constraint. I was updating the primary key of a table1 row, which was still being referenced by some table2 rows. These rows I had to update them too, so that the referencing column of table2 rows matched the updated primary key of table1's row. I changed the 'UPDATE' queries within the transaction and the problem got solved.

Sorry to put you into this. The solution was so simple, but that day I coudn't see it.

Comment: Thanks for the update--it's good to know you got it solved!  Why not give yourself the checkmark?