# Postgres Sequelize transaction with deferred constraint doesn't work

Tags: node.js, postgresql, transactions, sequelize.js, deferred

**Purpose:** 
I'm trying to made changes in related tables inside of transaction.

**Actions:**
I've altered constraint in table to set them `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` to be able to commit in referenced table inside of transaction. [Just like in this article.](http://dbadailystuff.com/deferred-constraints-in-postgresql)

So in my table there are two FK constraints:

```
Foreign-key constraints:
    "updaters_features_updater_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (updater_id) REFERENCES updaters(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "updaters_features_feature_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (feature_id) REFERENCES features(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

I'm starting transaction with:

```
sequelize.transaction({
    deferrable:  this.db.sequelize.Deferrable.SET_DEFERRED,
}, t => {
    //insert into updates table
    //insert into updates_features table 
})
```

It's generate next SQL query:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
INSERT INTO "public"."updaters" ("id","description","is_full","created_at","updated_at","android_model_id","version_from_id","version_to_id") VALUES (DEFAULT,'Description',true,'2019-12-18 09:46:21.272 +00:00','2019-12-18 09:46:21.272 +00:00',1,31,32) RETURNING *;
INSERT INTO "public"."updaters_features" ("created_at","updated_at","feature_id","updater_id") VALUES ('2019-12-18 09:46:21.267 +00:00','2019-12-18 09:46:21.267 +00:00',3,280),('2019-12-18 09:46:21.267 +00:00','2019-12-18 09:46:21.267 +00:00',5,280);
```

And it fails with foreign key constraint violation `Key (updater_id)=(280) is not present in table "updaters".`

I can't locate the problem and the most weird about it that if I'm copy SQL query from console and run it manually in `psql` - everything finishing well and I can commit transaction.

I was looking in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083076/setting-constraint-deferrable-doesnt-work-on-postgresql-transaction) but I have different problems.

**UPD (JS which applies transaction code):**

```
await this.withTransation({
    deferrable:  this.db.sequelize.Deferrable.SET_DEFERRED,
}, async(transaction) => {
    update = await this.dbModel.create({
        version_from_id: body.buildFrom,
        version_to_id: body.buildTo,
        android_model_id: body.modelId,
        description: body.description,
        isFull: body.isFull,
    }, {transaction});
    await this.db.UpdatersGroups.bulkCreate(body.groupIds.map((groupId) => ({
        feature_id: groupId,
        updater_id: update.id,
    })));
});
```

`withTransaction` is my abstraction which I'm sure works correctly (just create unmanaged transaction in sequelize)

Comment: the second INSERTION uses a hardcoded FK `280`. this is a bit strange. could You please share a JS code that does the insertion?

Comment: @AndreiPiatrou Sure. I've updated post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second query is not executed in a transaction context so adding a `transaction` should help:

```js
...
await this.db.UpdatersGroups.bulkCreate(body.groupIds.map((groupId) => ({
    feature_id: groupId,
    updater_id: update.id,
}), { transaction })); // transaction here is applied.
```

Comment: :facepalm: Thank you very much! I can't believe I've had so missed up!